# Cannot update document with Pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo, crud

I have a JSON POST data that a user is going to send me every time to fetch some data from a third party service.I plan to cache the data based on user_id so that I don't keep inserting the data each time the user requests for something.Below is the POST data that user is going to send me everytime

```
{
        "scope_id": "user1",
        "tool_id": "appdynamics",
        "api_id": "get metrics",
        "input_params": {"user": "*********", "pwd": "*********", "acc_id": "**********", "app_id": "TestApp", "metric-path": "ars", 
        "time-range-type": "BEFORE_NOW", "duration-in-mins": 60},
        "output_filters": {}
}
```

Below is my code snipped to handle the update of the data

```
def post(self, name):
    data = ServiceAPI.parser.parse_args()
    print("First data", data)
    scope_id = data["scope_id"]
    tool_id = data["tool_id"]
    api_id = data["api_id"]
    input_params = data["input_params"]
    output_filter = data["output_filter"]

    # if the user passes the credentials, insert it into the database otherwise use the last known credentials
        # ensure you only insert valid credentials
    if all([scope_id, tool_id, api_id]) and all([input_params.values()]):

        users.update({scope_id: [tool_id, api_id, input_params, datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]},
                     {scope_id: [tool_id, api_id, input_params, datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]}, upsert=True)
    print("Cache", list(users.find({})))
    status_code, response = api_executor(scope_id, tool_id, api_id)
    if status_code == 200:
        return {"message": response}, status_code
    return {"message": "Please enter correct credentials"}, status_code
```

However I keep getting the same data inserted into my database and update doesn't seem to work.How can I fix this?

Note: This is a flask app and I suggest not to get into the details of the implementation.I just need to update the given POST data each time and not insert it.

Answer (score 1):

The selector used in your update query *i.e.* `{'scope_id': [tool_id, api_id, input_params, datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]}` never matches any existing documents.

This is because it checks for a document whose `scope_id` is an array consisting of the current time.

Use:

```
selector = {'scope_id': {'$all': [tool_id, api_id, input_params]}}

update = {
    'scope_id': [
        tool_id, api_id, input_params, 
        datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
     ]
}
users.update(selector, update, upsert=True)
```